# How to get job.execute to run with drush

Tags: cron

I have the command in cron  `cd /home/quabbinm/ && /usr/local/bin/drush -r /home/quabbinm/public_html/trainingactivebystanders.org -l https://trainingactivebystanders.org -u nan civicrm-api job.execute`
which results in errors

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.33
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: argv in <b>phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush</b> on line <b>114</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in <b>phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>171</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>182</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  pcntl_exec() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in <b>phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>359</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant STDERR - assumed 'STDERR' in <b>phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>363</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>363</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant STDERR - assumed 'STDERR' in <b>phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>364</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in <b>phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc</b> on line <b>364</b><br />
```

When I run the same command at the command line it runs fine

Comment: two questions:
if you run drush manually on the command line do you get the same errors?

can you try to have your cron task cd into the site directory so you can run drush without having to give it the site parameters ?

Comment: When I run this at the command line it runs fine. I am doing a cd into the site directory. What are you suggesting otherwise?

Comment: I tried this cd /home/quabbinm/public_html/trainingactivebystanders.org && /usr/local/bin/drush -r https://trainingactivebystanders.org -u nan civicrm-api job.execute and get the message civicrm-api job.execute can't be found

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using an incorrect version of php when this command runs from cron. According to [this resource](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush/issues/1961862) you are receiving these errors because you are using php-cgi rather than the php CLI binary. Most reports of this error are regarding 1 & 1 hosting.

Rather than using /usr/bin/drush use something like this:

> /usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/drush {rest of the command}

Where /usr/bin/php is the path to the php CLI binary on your system.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to the crontab file:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing.  It helps if you explain why you are recommending something and how it helps solve the issue.  Since the command in cron is using absolute paths, it is not obvious why setting the path variable will make any difference.